# gnome-shell stopped working after last update

Tags: 11.10, gnome

After an update 3 days ago gnome-shell stopped working, trying to restart it with `gnome-shell --replace` only results in another crash and the keyboard stops working.

This is what I get when trying to start gnome-shell:

```
st_widget_get_theme_node called on the widget [0x24112a0 StButton.status-chooser-user-icon] which is not in the stage.
```

gnome-shell-calendar-server[4829]: Got HUP on stdin - exiting
Trace/breakpoint trap

If I look in the `xorg.0.log` I got this error:

```
gnome-session[5321]: WARNING: App 'gnome-shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
```

and

```
: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

Ran `metacity --replace` just to get the window borders back for now. The interesting thing is if I log in to xfce I got the same problem, no window boarders, must run `metacity --replace` in xfce also.

Running Ubuntu 11.10 with gnome-shell 3.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the gnome-shell Alternative Status Menu extension:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=739271

You can try the workarounds suggested in the previous link, or read here for how to remove the extension:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#When_an_extension_breaks_GNOME

Answer (score -1):

[Try this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem%3a__Need_to_fully_remove_-fglrx_and_reinstall_-ati_from_scratch)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.